# Failing to modify .bashrc

Tags: bash

My `.bashrc` file contains:

```
# mkdir, cd into it
function mkcd () 
{
    mkdir -p "$*"
    cd "$*"
}
```

When I type `mkcd` in shell I get `mkcd: Command not found`. 
when I type `source ~/.bashrc` I get an error:

`Badly placed ()'s.`

by the way, my text editor (emacs) is recognising the code as `Shell-script[tcsh]`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Did you run `source ~/.bashrc` after editing it?

Comment: Wrong shell.  `Badly placed ()'s` is a message produced by `tcsh`. Switch to `bash` or `ksh`.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld thank you, that solved it. I was shamefully unaware that bash and default ubuntu terminal were different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can accept the restriction that you have to pass the name of the directory to be created as the first argument, it should look like this:

```
# mkdir, cd into it
function mkcd () 
{
    mkdir -p "$@"
    cd "$1"
}
```

You need to run `source ~/.bashrc` to see it working (or alternatively start a new shell).

Comment: when I do that I get `Badly placed ()'s.` when I drop the `()` I get `function: Command not found.
{: Command not found.
Illegal variable name.`

Comment: thank you, that solved it. I was shamefully unaware that bash and default ubuntu terminal were different.

Comment: yeah, ubuntu is using `dash` by default :)

Comment: really? but I had to type `bash` in order to enter the bash environment on the ubuntu terminal

Comment: (By the way, I've reworded my question, so if you could help to take off the "on hold as off-topic" that would be great!)

Answer (score 2):

Three comments on that function.  This will work *mostly*.  To catch some corner cases:

1. Either use `function mkcd { ...; }` or `mkcd() { ...; }`.  The first is compatible with `ksh`, but only if you drop the `()`.  The `mkcd()` notation is the standard POSIX notation.
2. Even `mkdir -p` can fail, so make the `cd` conditional on `mkdir`.
3. Finally, you want exactly one argument to `mkdir` and `cd`.  Use only one argument, and test that it has a value with the `:?` modifier in parameter substitution.  This will stop the function from sending you `$HOME`.

Together:

```ksh
function mkcd
{
    mkdir -p "${1:?}" && cd "${1}"
}
```

Put that in your .bashrc and open a new shell.  Type `type mkcd`.  This should respond with:

`mkcd is a function`, followed by its definition.

Comment: when I drop `()`, add `;` and type `source ~.bashrc`, I get  
    `function: Command not found.
    {: Command not found.
    Bad : modifier in $ (?).`

Comment: when I paste the code you suggested in /.bashrc, open new shell and type `type mkcd` I get `cat: mkcd: No such file or directory`. when I type `source ~/.bashrc` I get `function: Command not found.
{: Command not found.
Bad : modifier in $ (?).`

Answer (score 1):

I ran your mkcd function on bash 4.2.45 and linux 3.8.0 and it worked as expected.  Logging on in a fresh window or running

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

in your existing window should define the function for you.  If it does not work you'll get an error message like:

```
mkcd: command not found
```

While hek2mgl's suggestion is not necessary to make it work, it does make it make more sense since you're only going to cd to one directory.

Comment: actually I got `function: Command not found.
{: Command not found.
Bad : modifier in $ (?).` as an error message. what do you think that means?

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Henk Langeveld and hek2mgl: "Wrong shell. Badly placed ()'s is a message produced by tcsh. Switch to bash or ksh."

I thought that opening a terminal on ubuntu entered straight into bash environment. In fact, as commented below, "a Terminal will start a copy of your login shell as defined in /etc/passwd". By typing `ps -p $$` in terminal, I realise mine is set to tcsh, the C shell. In that case, one needs to type `bash` to get into bash environment.

Then `source ~/.bashrc` compiles the definition for mkcd.

Comment: A Terminal will start a copy of your login shell as defined in `/etc/passwd`.  This can be overruled by the `$SHELL` environment variable at the time of invocation, or in the *Terminal* session definitions for setting a command in place of our shell.